# Pagination with Template Routes

Tags: pagination

I have this page for showing articles, and I want to have links below the article to paginate to the next and previous.

This is my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" dynamic="yes" url_title="{segment:article}" status="open|featured" paginate="bottom"}
  <section class="block block--intro">
   <div class="panel">
    &lt;header class="panel__heading"&gt;
     <h1>{title}</h1>
    &lt;/header&gt;
    <div class="panel__body">
     <figure>
      {exp:ce_img:pair src="{article_featured_image}"}
       <img src="{made}" alt="" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
      {/exp:ce_img:pair}
     </figure>

    </div>
    <footer class="panel__footer">
     <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline meta">
      <li><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Written by {author}</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i><time>{entry_date format="%F %j%S %Y"}</time></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-folder-o fa-fw"></i>{categories}{category_name}, {/categories}</li>
     </ul>
    </footer>

   </div>
  </section>

  <main>
   <article class="article">
    <div class="wrapper">

          {article_content}


    </div>
   </article>

   {paginate}
    {if previous_page}
     <a href="{auto_path}">Previous Page</a> &nbsp;
    {/if}
    {if next_page}
     <a href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>
    {/if}
   {/paginate}

  </main>



  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

For my Template Route for this template I have:

articles/{article:alpha_dash} and set Segments Required to Yes.

What am I doing wrong? No code is being displayed for the pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{paginate}` tag is used to paginate multiple results on list pages. Since you are on a detail page and you are trying to link to next / previous entries in the articles channel, have you tried using the [next / previous entry links](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html) instead?

Also, since you are using routes and url_title, you don't need EE to look at the URL structure. I would use `dynamic="no"`. I would also use `limit="1"` in there.

Comment: Brilliant, this works a treat.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of some help.